# Multiple parallel scheduled Tasks in BackgroundService

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a backgroundservice in my blazor ss application that looks like the following and a scan class for context:

```
public class AutoscanBgService : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
    private readonly ILogger<AutoscanBgService> _logger;
    
    public AutoscanBgService(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Timed Hosted Service AutoScanBgService running.");

        List<Scan> scanList;

        using (IServiceScope scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
        {
            var uow = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IUnitOfWork>();
            scanList = await uow.IScanRepository.GetActive();
        }

        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            foreach (var scan in scanList)
            {
                Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
                {
                    Task.Delay(
                        UntilNextExecution(CrontabSchedule.Parse(scan.CronSchedule).GetNextOccurrence(DateTime.Now)),
                        stoppingToken); // wait until next time
                    await DoWork(scan);
                }, stoppingToken);
            }
        }
    }

    private async Task DoWork(Scan scan)
    {
        using (IServiceScope scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
        {
            var pingService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<PingService>();
            await pingService.ScanNetwork(scan.Network);
        }
        
        scan.FirstExecuted ??= DateTime.Now;
        scan.LastExecuted = DateTime.Now;
    }
    
    private int UntilNextExecution(DateTime _nextRun) => Math.Max(0, (int)_nextRun.Subtract(DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds);

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) => Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

**Scan class**

```
public class Scan
{
    public int ScanId { get; set; }
    public int NetworkId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("NetworkId")]
    public Network Network { get; set; }
    public string CronSchedule { get; set; }
    public DateTime? FirstExecuted { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastExecuted { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; } = true;
}
```

My goal is to permanently run this service in the background and for it to go through all scans in parallel, create a Task for each scan that will wait until the cron converted schedule time is reached and then repeat.

I know how to do this when all tasks are started / stopped at the same time but **I need to start a new task once the previous task with the same scan property has been finished.**

The problem is that the while loop obviously keeps creating tasks because I neither await nor check for completion anywhere, but I don't know how to do this with multiple Tasks.

Does anyone know how I could structure this / point me to a solution?

Thanks!

Comment: You could always make use of a `List<Task> tasks`, add all "tasks" to carry out to the list of tasks and perform an `var result = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);` and this way you can get the result of all tasks and work through the results.

Comment: If you want, I can put an answer down with the approach I would take?

Comment: [This looks useful](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-based-asynchronous-programming)

Comment: @Tagz97 Im sorry I think I didn't describe my usecase very well. I know how to do this when all tasks are started / stopped at the same time but I need to start a new task once the previous task with the same scan property has been finished.

Comment: No worries! I will remove my answer as not applicable